# Custom title using URI segment

Tags: craft3, php

I am working on my SEO and I am getting a duplicate title in Craft.
I want to make a custom title using the URI segment in using PHP.

Comment: Can you give an example, using a URI and then the Title you would like to see?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this in your main layout template. You'll need to add a filter after "segments" to get the URI segment you want, e.g.: `|first` or `|last`, and you'll also need to [|replace](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/filters.html#replace) any hyphens and then [|capitalize](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/capitalize.html) the first letter of the result.

```
{% set myUri = craft.app.request.segments %}

<title>{{ myUri }}</title>
```

For more on segments: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/changes-in-craft-3.html#template-functions